# Issue in installing SSIS MS-SQL2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

While installing the MS SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition, everything goes through fine but I'm not able to install Integration Services alone. I get the error as following:

> The following error has
>   occurred:C:\SQLserver....\Binn\DTSSVCPERF.ini Click retry to retry
>   the failed action.

I have tried re-installing many times, but still am facing the same issue.
The OS is Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Can you please post the complete error or a screenshot as the error posted seems not sufficient to answer.

Comment: Do you want to see the summary log? because the screenshot shows only the error which I have quoted in the question.

Comment: Can you check the error log if it contains more information? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702.aspx

Answer (score -1):

The problem is apparently not related to just SQL 2012; it has been reported on older versions also.

One guess is that your copy of SQL Server is probably corrupt. You could try downloading from a different source and checking if the issue repeats. The new SQL Server download might have all the required files in good condition, and save you the headache of any issues down the line. Of course, you should uninstall everything before attempting a fresh install from a different source.

You mentioned that it was Enterprise Edition? Assuming that it's a licensed copy,  you can also call Microsoft Support and ask them for assistance.